# Why does a PingFederate IdP connection require a SP adapter?

Tags: pingfederate

I have read the PingFederate documentation and it says:

> An SP adapter is used to create a local-application session for a user
>   in order for PingFederate® to provide SSO access to your applications
>   or other protected resources. You must configure at least one instance
>   of an SP adapter in order to set up connections to IdP partners. You
>   can also configure multiple instances of adapters (based on one or
>   more adapters) to accommodate the varying needs of your IdP partners.

But I don't understand why the IdP connection requires a SP adapter? Why is it required and what does it really do?

In my use case I use PingFederate as an OAuth server and authenticates the users via SP-initiated SSO to external IDPs and then in the OAuth Attribute Mapping of the connection I map the Assertion attributes directly into the persistent grant. Why does not this suffice, I dont understand the need for the SP adapter? How and who is intended to reference the adapter more that the IdP connection itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely right, in some cases (like yours) an SP adapter is unnecessary.

Under your IdP Connection, under **Browser SSO > User-Session Creation > Identity Mapping** there is an option for "No Mapping" which will avoid having to map into an SP adapter. For more details see: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=uql1564003010611.html

The "No Mapping" option was introduced in PingFederate 8.1, so if you're on an earlier release it may not be available. In that case a "dummy" SP adapter should be mapped into your connection (even though it may not be used).